# Unable to instantiate PayPal service interface using configuration map

Tags: java, initialization, properties-file, paypal

**UPDATE 2**

### This is now resolved by PayPal in their SDK.

**UPDATE**

Looks like this is a known issue, see https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-java/issues/24 & https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-java/issues/53

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I am using Java SDK for Paypal's Merchant APIs.

For instantiating the PayPal service I provide a configuation map, instead of putting it in a `sdk_config.properties` file.

I know for a fact that this type of dynamic initialization should work. It's mentioned in their docs [here](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-java#to-make-an-api-call).

When I call a specific service I get `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` caused by `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Resource 'sdk_config.properties' could not be found`

But that's the thing I am not using stattic init method, so there is no point of having a proeprties file.

Here is the snippet of code I am using,

```
Map<String, String> configMap = Maps.newHashMap();
        configMap.put("mode", "sandbox");
        configMap.put("acct1.UserName", "username");
        configMap.put("acct1.Password", "password");
        configMap.put("acct1.Signature", "signature");

PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(configMap);

service.setExpressCheckout(...)
```

Not sure what is wrong about this.

Comment: Issue was resolved by PayPal in their core Java SDK.

Comment: This question is the best documentation on what to put in the map (docs are a joke), where do you get the values though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now resolved by PayPal in their SDK.